# Neo4j Documentation

Tags: configuration, documentation, installation, neo4j

I've been looking into setting up and trying out Neo4j on Amazon EC2 however I seem to have hit a road block with finding documentation that I can use.

For example, this page mentions "Clustering, High Availability and Online Backup are add-on components that manage distribution and consistency over several live or offline node spaces."  However, I haven't been able to find any more information on these add-ons.
http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Neo4j_in_the_Cloud

This seemingly key wiki page describing how to set up Neo4j seems to be missing some very information.
http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Neo4j_Setup_HowTo

Is anyone else using this and referencing better documentation, or am I completely missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some related info [at this link](http://nowiki.neo4j.org/content/Neo4j_in_the_Cloud), although the setup might depend a bit your requirements. The HA support is currently in beta, we will be able to let you test it as soon as Neo4j 1.0 is out of the door, which is before end of Jan 2010.